# Delphi Tinifile.ReadString and PromptDataSource

Tags: delphi

The first, click button1,can get the [section].[Key].Value

but if change the path via the second page's `[...]` of PromptDataSource()

Then the next time, click button1, can not get the [section].[Key].Value

## Why???

---

#### Awe.dat

```
[Options]
DBConnection=Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=D:\2000.mdb;
```

---

#### the Button1Click's code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Filename:string;
  DatFile:TiniFile;
  str:WideString;
  ConnectStr:WideString;
begin
  DatFile:=Tinifile.Create('.\Awe.dat');
  str:=DatFile.ReadString('Options','DBConnection','');
    ShowMessage(str+'-----------------');
  ConnectStr:=PromptDataSource(handle,str);
    ShowMessage(str+'-----------------'+ConnectStr);
  DatFile.Free;
end;
```

---

Comment: Have you tried reading all sections with ReadSections() to see, if your file is parsed correctly?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. I'd also comment that you had better hope that the process current directory is what you think it is. You also miss a try finally and so run the gauntlet of a memory leak.

Comment: @Nine What encoding of your Awe.dat file? Ensure that is ANSI.

Comment: The first time, can get the [section] .[Key].Value, but, as long as the change in PromptDataSource()'s second page, the next time you can not get the value

Comment: Try callling [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(VS.85).aspx) after `ReadString` to find out if the file wasn't found.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the process current directory is what you expect it to be?

Comment: GetLastError  is ok .@Craig Young . And  I sure in the demo.@David Heffernan

Comment: God,That's my fault.THANK TO @CraigYoung.

Comment: Try using an absolute path

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  It run. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to your use of a relative path. Your path is relative to the process working directory.

If the working directory is in your complete control then your code would be fine. But often the working directory is not in your complete control. The process may start with an unexpected working directory. File dialogs may change the working directory.

You are better being explicit and providing a full path to the file. It looks like your file is in the same directory as the executable. So you could use:

```
ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + FileName
```

or similar.